# Sorting an Array List of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I'm reading game scores from a text file into an ArrayList. Each item in the ArrayList is a String array with 2 indexes, one stores the player's name and the other the score.

What's the best way from here to sort the list into numerical order by the score, in order to display high scores?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "best"? There are lots of ways, some simple, some complex, all of them effort compared to just using a built-in sorter like Collections.sort

Comment: you could use `Collections.sort()` and write your custom `comparator`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I meant simplest I guess. How would I use Collections.sort here?

Comment: @BatScream has you covered there. `Collections.sort` is well documented, as is the concept of using it in combination with a `Comparator` object, simply search for them within the context of java and you'll find *lots* of tutorials that explain how to use them. Or search Stackoverflow for it, plenty of questions that involve using Collections.sort, too.

Comment: Probably you would be better off with a custom data structure - something like PlayerScore - when your data is as firmly structured as this.  And have a List of those, instead of a List of Lists.  Then make your class implement Comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look something like this, assuming the score is stored in index 1:

```
Collections.sort(playerList, new Comparator<String[]>(){
   @Override
   public int compare(String[] player1, String[] player2) {
         return Integer.parseInt(player1[1]) - Integer.parseInt(player2[1]);
     }
 }
```

`playerList` is the list of your arrays. This method will sort the array list for you using the supplied `Comparator` object which, as you see, takes two elements from the ArrayList and supplies a method of determining which one is first.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not forced to use an array to store the score, then I recommend using a dedicated model class for it, that implements the `Comparable` interface.

```
public class Score implements Comparable<Score> {
    final String name;
    final int score;

    public Score(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Score that) {
        return that.score - this.score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Score[name=%s, score=%d]", name, score);
    }
}
```

The current implementation sorts `descending`. If you want to sort `ascending`, then change it to `return this.score - that.score;`.

You can use that class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    scores.add(new Score("Mike", 100));
    scores.add(new Score("Jenny", 250));
    scores.add(new Score("Gary", 75));
    scores.add(new Score("Nicole", 110));

    Collections.sort(scores);

    for (final Score score : scores) {
        System.out.println(score);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Score[name=Jenny, score=250]
Score[name=Nicole, score=110]
Score[name=Mike, score=100]
Score[name=Gary, score=75]
```